# How to perform AES gcm encryption using Python PYKCS11

Tags: python, pkcs#11

I am trying to simulate an AES-GCM encryption using soft-HSM and Python PyKCS11 library.
according to Oasis documentation. C_EncryptFinal needs to be called after C_Encrypt step to get Ciphertext and tag. I am not sure whether the library mechanism calls the EncryptFinal automatically, cause the ciphertext i get doesn't include the tag.

```
    import PyKCS11
    from PyKCS11 import LowLevel
    from PyKCS11 import PyKCS11Lib
    import os
    from PyKCS11 import *
    
    pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
    pkcs11.load('C:\\SoftHSM2\\lib\\softhsm2-x64.dll')
    
    slot = pkcs11.getSlotList(tokenPresent=True)[0]
    # print(pkcs11.getSlotInfo(slot))
    # print(slot)
    
    session = pkcs11.openSession(slot, PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    
    session.login('Simple10!')
    
    
    def generatesessionkey():
        AES_TEMPLATE = [
            (LowLevel.CKA_CLASS, LowLevel.CKO_SECRET_KEY),
            (LowLevel.CKA_KEY_TYPE, LowLevel.CKK_AES),
            (LowLevel.CKA_LABEL, "aes-256key234234234"),
            (LowLevel.CKA_VALUE_LEN, "32"),
            (LowLevel.CKA_TOKEN, CK_TRUE)
        ]
        key = session.generateKey(AES_TEMPLATE, PyKCS11.MechanismAESGENERATEKEY)
        return key
    
    
    # print(session.findObjects([(LowLevel.CKA_CLASS,LowLevel.CKO_SECRET_KEY)]))
    
    
    encryption_key = session.findObjects([(LowLevel.CKA_LABEL, "aes-256key234234234")])[0]
     
    
    def AES_encryption():
        Nonce = session.generateRandom(96 // 8)
        M = PyKCS11.AES_GCM_Mechanism(iv=Nonce, aad=b'test', tagBits=16)
        ciphertext = session.encrypt(encryption_key, b'Hello World', M)
        return bytes(ciphertext)
AES_encryption()
```